PayPal Smart/Hosted Button: callback on Approve/Capture
I am switching out a script block which used to use the subscription feature of PayPal. The code was basically this:
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=[id]=true&intent=subscription" data-sdk-integration-source="button-factory"></script>
<div id="paypal-button-container-P-[id]"></div>
<script>
    paypal.Buttons({
        style: {
             shape: 'rect',
             color: 'gold',
             layout: 'vertical',
             label: 'subscribe'
            },
        createSubscription: function(data, actions) {
            return actions.subscription.create({
            /* Creates the subscription */
            plan_id: 'P-[id]'
            });
        },
        onApprove: function(data, actions) {
            var subId = document.getElementById('subId');
            subId.setAttribute('value',  data.subscriptionID);
            var form = document.getElementById('membershipForm');
            form.submit();
        }
}).render('#paypal-button-container-P-[id]'); // Renders the PayPal button
</script>

After the payment goes through, I run the onApprove callback function to submit a form on the page with some site-specific information, and sends emails through the website.
The payment model has changed, and now we want to use single payments, not subscriptions.
I have tried using the "No-Code Checkout" AKA "HostedButton" AKA "Smart Buttons". It generates this:
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=[id]&components=hosted-buttons&disable-funding=venmo&currency=CAD"></script>
<div id="paypal-container-[id]"></div>
<script>
paypal.HostedButtons({
    hostedButtonId: "[id]"
}).render("#paypal-container-[id]")
</script>

There's no callback function in here. When someone finishes paying, they stay on the page and there is no feedback from the website or indication the transaction was made other than the pop-up closes.
I tried adding onApprove like before, but still nothing happens. Even simplifying the callback function to a console.log or alert does nothing. It doesn't seem to ever get called.
paypal.HostedButtons({
    hostedButtonId: "[id]",
    onApprove: function(data, actions) {
    var subId = document.getElementById('subId');
        subId.setAttribute('value',  data.subscriptionID);
        var form = document.getElementById('membershipForm');
        form.submit();
        }
}).render("#paypal-container-[id]")

I've scoured PayPal's documentation but I can't find anything on this.
If it makes a difference, this is a button made in sandbox, being purchased with a sandbox test account, running everything on localhost.
Also note: there are no errors at any point in this process, and my sandbox account is getting the money.

The "No Code" / "HostedButtons" JS integration is new and quite limited in how much it can be customized/extended; there is no callback function as of this writing. (Presumably one may be added in the future)
For now you'll need to use a standard integration, creating and capturing orders with a backend using the v2/checkout/orders API.

Is that really how Paypal functions right now? The standard integration sets the price client-side. Meaning anyone could change the price before hitting pay. I can't believe this is standard. Surely the people who use paypal for their website are not doing this.

The standard integration does not set the price client-side. Item information is sent to a server and the server manages pricing and payment capture.
